# LDAP search to find what group x user belong into PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am using Microsoft Active directory to allow people access to my network. Now I am trying to build a PHP page so the same uses who have access to my network have access to my PHP page. However, I want to give people rights so if your in the managers group then you can edit the page if not then you can view only so on and so forth.

I have been reading and looking at example but what I don't understand the base of the Active directory. 
This example was detailed http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php#107545 but what I don't understand is

```
  $dn = "DC=whatever,DC=whatever";
```

And also the field's names in the search array

```
  $LDAPFieldsToFind = array("cn", "givenname", "samaccountname", "homedirectory", "telephonenumber", "mail");
```

Here is how my my active directory looks like
-Domain.com
   +Administrators
   +Managers
   -Limited_users
       +Department_name1
       +Department_name2
   +IT Department

Question: after binding the user how to search to know what directory this user was found in?

Thanks

Comment: See if the script I posted for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351602/php-ldap-get-user-attributes-including-associated-groups/14364301#14364301) will help you.

Comment: That does help a bit but I still don't understand what values I need to put for DC

Comment: The script I use has: `DC=our_domain_name_here,DC=local`.

Comment: What is local? I am trying to understand this so I can replace those values by values from my active directory and also what is this exactly? (&(objectCategory=person))

Comment: These [pages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755809%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) might be [helpful](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx). I'm actually "the Linux guy" so I know very little about Active Directory. The `local` piece comes into play because our local domain is `local.our_domain_name`

Comment: Thanks for that information. That did help explain a lot but I am still unable to do the search. I am able to bind to my Active directory.  I think this is where IU am going wrong  DC=domain.com,DC=local  <<< I think this is the problem I am not sure what to do here

Comment: Have you tried `DC=domain,DC=com`?

Answer (score 0):

@Benny.  Thank you for your help I finally figured it out. I have downloaded this file which have me the exact base http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx