# Search and Modify Users in active directory without OU filters php

Tags: php

```
//In my Config file (config.php)
```

```
$dn = "CN=" . $_POST['cn'] . ",OU=" . $cn . ",DC=" . $dc1. ",DC=" . $dc2;

$attributes = array("cn" , "mail" ,"sAMAccountName", "thumbnailPhoto", "url" ,  "displayName", "physicaldeliveryofficename" , "telephonenumber"    ,"mobile","ipphone","facsimiletelephonenumber","title","department");

$ad = ldap_connect($fqdn)or die("Couldn't connect to AD!");

ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bd = ldap_bind($ad, $login_name, $password) or die("Couldn't bind to AD!");
```

Any suggestions? Below is my code ... I need to search a domain name active directory irrespective of the OU structure to cater for future changes instead of hard coding the OU filters.

```
// In my update file (update.php) 

$result = ldap_mod_replace($ad, $dn, $user);
//$result = ldap_modify($ad, $dn, $user);

if($result){ 
    //echo "User modified!";
    header("Location: personal.php?update=yes");
}

ldap_unbind($ad);
```

This code refuses to update for all users works for some users only within the active directory tree.

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Where are you defining $fqdn?

Comment: If you are up for changing how you are connecting to AD, check out the adldap library. It allows you to create users and modify current user attributes. Based on the documentation for the modify() method you only specify the username. http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_user_functions

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351602/php-ldap-get-user-attributes-including-associated-groups/14364301#14364301) help you?

Comment: @Robbert : I have developed a webform which allows for users to update the active directory details. The system is able to update the account for some users but for the account for the director of the organisations and his secretary, it pops up this error "undefined function ldap_mod_replace($ad, $dn, $user)". $dn for the connection to the AD, $dn for the distinguished name and $user for the user attribute to modify.

Comment: I would try to figure out what the actual values for $ad, $dn and $user are and check to see that they match what you think they are supposed to be.  If it works for some users but not others, then it could be a matter of permissions to the object or something else happening in the code you haven't shared with us.